# Difference between Voltage and Effective voltage (Sinusoidal voltage)

Tags: electric-current, voltage

I know this has been asked already but I didn't really find what I was looking for. Physically, the voltage is the difference of potential that triggers electrons to move from their position to another.  My question: what is the effective voltage and what is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

For a sinusoidal voltage, there is the *instantaneous* voltage

$$v(t) = V_P\cos(\omega\,t + \phi)$$

the *peak* voltage $V_P$, the *peak-to-peak* voltage

$$V_{PP} = 2V_P$$

and the *RMS* voltage

$$V_{RMS} = V_P/\sqrt{2} \approx V_P\cdot 0.707$$

The *RMS* voltage gives the equivalent DC voltage for the same average power delivered to a resistor. Is this the effective voltage you're asking about?

In the case of a full-wave rectified (absolute value of a) sinusoidal voltage, there is also a non-zero *average* voltage

$$V_{AVG} \approx V_P\cdot 0.637$$

Answer (score 0):

"Effective voltage" is not a widely known term with a universal meaning. It means whatever the context says it means.

For example, if you had a 10 V source, but for some reason it only effects a circuit as if it were a 5 V source, we might call that the effective voltage.

> I meant the one that's equal to the peak voltage divided by square root of 2

This is more commonly called the "root-mean-square" or "RMS" voltage of the AC signal. It can be called the "effective voltage" because it is the DC voltage that would deliver the same power to a resistive load.

But I don't think anybody I've ever worked with would realize this is what you meant by "effective voltage" if you used the term without context.

Comment: Ah, I see.
I meant the one that's equal to the peak voltage divided by square root of 2.

Comment: Actually, _effective voltage_ (or value for a generic quantity) is the standard term for RMS voltage in several languages. You can have a look at [this entry](http://www.electropedia.org/iev/iev.nsf/display?openform&ievref=103-02-03) in the IEC Electrotechnical Vocabulary which reports the term in different languages.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, The IEC vocabulary is practically unknown to American engineers in my experience. You shouldn't count on terms from it being understood by Americans. Obviously it could be much more carefully observed in other countries.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, for example, they also list "tension" as a synonym for voltage, but this is simply not used outside of the idiomatic term "high tension line" by any American I know, and AFAIK it's also not used in the UK.

Comment: @ThePhoton The point is that if the OP is not from the US they might be more used to the other terminology.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, all the more reason we should inform them about the usual usage in English.